Generate random trajectory for aircraft in 3D world (Python)
I have a 3D world in Python with terrain where I want to be able to generate airplanes flying in the world with random trajectories. The terrain should be some type of constraint so the airplanes do not fly through the ground or mountains (of course not reasonable). The trajectories should also be plausible for an aircraft, i.e. a quite smooth trajectory. I was thinking about generating random initial and end positions and using an algorithm to create the trajectory between those.
I therefore looked into particle swarm optimization, ant colony optimization, and random walk but I don't know if any of these fit the purpose. Does anyone know what would be good to use for this? Thanks!
